# Tem como criar em C# uma Propriedade do tipo array de string com 2 posições?

Tags: c#

Tenho as seguintes propriedades em um model:

```
public List<string[]> Imagens { get; set; }

public string[] Video { get; set; }

public string[] Audio { get; set; }
```

Lá no meu Controller eu estou verificando se o `ModelState.isValid`

Só que eu queria que o array de string na lista de imagens fosse com duas posições. Mas eu não sei como criar isso. 
Minha tentativa foi criar assim

```
public List<string[2]> Imagens { get; set; }
```

Mas não funciona, e eu preciso que o array tenha 2 valores dentro.

Comment: Como você está enviando o array de `Imagens` do seu `Form` se você mandar 2 itens que são array de string com o nome Imagens é carregado automaticamente!? O que está em jogo agora é você colocar o seu form e explificar o que está fazendo. Ah o Controller também!

Comment: Você quer criar um *array* com duas *strings*  ou quer uma *string* que tenha só 2 caracteres? Esse caracteres estão em qual  *encoding*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe no .NET nativamente um tipo que represente um array de tamanho fixo, criticando já na compilação caso seja ultrapassado o limite do mesmo.

O que você pode fazer neste caso é inicializar o array com tamanho fixo no construtor e impedí-lo de ser substituído por outro array alterando o escopo do *setter* da sua propriedade.

Algo assim:

```
class MinhaClasse
{
    public string[] Imagens { get; private set; }

    public MinhaClasse()
    {
        this.Imagens = new string[2];
    }

}
```

Penso, porém, que esta não é a melhor solução para o que procuras. O mais recomendável neste caso seria construir uma classe própria que represente de fato o que essa propriedade representa.

Exemplo:

```
class MinhaClasse
{
    public ConjuntoImagens Imagens { get; set; }
}

class ConjuntoImagens
{
    public string CaminhoImagemPequena { get; set; }
    public string CaminhoImagemGrande { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um `custom validate` mais ou menos assim:

```
public class MaxLengthArrayImgs : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly int _minElements;

    public MaxLengthArrayImgs (int minElements)
    {
        _minElements = minElements;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var list = value as IList;
        if (list != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var arr = item as string[];
                if (arr.length > minElements)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}


[MaxLengthArrayImgs(2, ErrorMessage = "OverFlow")]
public List<string[2]> Imagens { get; set; }
```